# Null pointer exception at Fragment

Tags: android

I am getting an `null pointer exception` while trying to implement these code in tab. That time I got an error at run time.

**StackTrace:**

```
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560): Process: com.gems.android, PID: 5560
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.sit.gems.frgment.AudioFragment.onCreateView(AudioFragment.java:24)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-05 08:40:53.884: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**AudioFragment.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import com.gems.android.R;
import com.sit.gems.app.BaseFragment;
import com.sit.gems.util.Utilities;
//import android.util.Log;

public class AudioFragment extends BaseFragment
{
    int mFlipping = 0;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1); //---- > Error
        /* Start Flipping */
        flipper.startFlipping();
        mFlipping = 1;

        return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null);
    }
}
```

**slide_left.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_in_left"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: view is null there... define value to view first then use it..

Comment: you're initializing the `view` in the `return` statement and you are using it beforehand. Of course it is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `View` object is `null` where you used it.

Try this:

```
public class AudioFragment extends BaseFragment  { 
    int mFlipping = 0 ;
    private View view;
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null);

        ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1); ---->Error 


            /** Start Flipping */ 
            flipper.startFlipping();
            mFlipping=1;

        return view;

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating your `R.layout.slide_left` layout and instantiating `view` **after** you have already tried to use it. In your current code, `view` is `null` when you try to interact with it. It needs to be inflated **before** you try to use it. So you need to change this;

```
ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1); // Error 
    /** Start Flipping */
    flipper.startFlipping();
    mFlipping=1;
return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null);
```

To this;

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null);
ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1); // No Error 
    /** Start Flipping */
    flipper.startFlipping();
    mFlipping=1;
return view;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should define "view" variable... Something like:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Then you will be able to call:

```
ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using view variable but you have not defined value to it...
so first define value to it and then use it...

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null, false);
```

This Should Be Something like that...............

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_left, null, false);
        ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.flipper1); ---->Error solved 

        /** Your Code... */


        return view;

    }
```